# a list from a list comprehension, find number of vowels in a string

Tags: python, pandas, list, list-comprehension

i am trying to write a function which goes through a `np.array` which contains emails and i want to obtain the number of vowels that are present in the email in a form of array

my try is:

```
def number_of_vouls(email):
    vouls = 'aeiouAEIOU'
    name = [e.split('@')[0] for e in email]
    return [sum(1 for c in name if c in vouls) for n in name]

number_of_vouls(np.array(['aaaab@yahoo.com', 'lingardo.pev@gmail.com']))

output: [0, 0]
```

The expected outout should be : `[5, 4]` for this case

My problem i think is that i am not able to loop by characters inside `name` but not sure how to solve it

Comment: Is there a particular reason for using a numpy array? Not that it's inherently wrong but seems unnecessary

Answer (score 5):

Just change name to n in the sum function

```
def number_of_vouls(email):
    vouls = 'aeiouAEIOU'
    name = [e.split('@')[0] for e in email]
    return [sum(1 for c in n if c in vouls) for n in name]

number_of_vouls(np.array(['aaaab@yahoo.com', 'lingardo.pev@gmail.com'])
```

Comment: Output: [4, 4] (There are four vowels and not five in the first email)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this instead :

```
emails = ["aaaab@yahoo.com","lingardo.pev@gmail.com"]

vowels = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
count = 0
result = []

for email in emails:
    words = email.split("@")
    for char in words[0]:
        if char.lower() in vowels:
            count+=1

    result.append(count)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be:

```
def number_of_vouls(email):
    vouls = 'aeiouAEIOU'
    name = [e.split('@')[0] for e in email]
    return [len([a for a in n if vouls.find(a) != -1]) for n in name]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways to do this. Here's another method:

```
VOWELS = {*'aeiouAEIOU'}

def number_of_vowels(emails):
    result = []
    for email in emails:
        localpart, *_ = email.split('@')
        result.append(sum(map(lambda x: x in VOWELS, localpart)))
    return result

print(number_of_vowels(['aaaab@yahoo.com', 'lingardo.pev@gmail.com']))
```

Comment: Hi! Why not simply using `set` instead of `{*'...'}`?

Comment: @cards less typing

Answer (score 0):

Since you're working with numpy arrays, you might want to take a look at the [vectorize](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) function:

```
number_of_vouls = np.vectorize(lambda x: sum([1 if y in "aeiou" else 0 for y in x.split("@")[0].lower()]))
print(number_of_vouls(np.array(['aaaab@yahoo.com', 'lingardo.pev@gmail.com'])))
```

Answer (score 0):

Used *lower case* vouls characters and then count them with `casefold` approach.

```
import numpy as np

def number_of_vouls(email):
    vouls = 'aeiou'
    names = [e.split('@')[0] for e in email]
    
    return [sum(name.casefold().count(v) for v in vouls) for name in names]
    
emails = np.array(['aAAab@yahoo.com', 'lingardo.pev@gmail.com', 'sOme_gUy@yahoo.com'])
v = number_of_vouls(emails)
```

Output

```
[4, 4, 3]
```